# How to crop a small area from leaflet or tmap

Tags: r, leaflet, tmap

Could someone show me how to crop this lake from a leaflet or tmap? Code and screenshot below:

```
library(sf)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
library(leaflet)
 
test <- tm_basemap(c("Esri.DeLorme")) + 
tm_shape(onepoint) + tm_markers() + tm_view(set.view = c(lon = -120.02, lat = 39.100,zoom=11)) 
test

#Or with leaflet
leaflet() %>%
addProviderTiles("Esri.Delorme") %>%
  setView(lng = -120.02, lat = 39.100, zoom = 11)
  
  leaflet() %>% 
addTiles() %>%  
  setView(lng = -120.02, lat = 39.100, zoom = 11)
```

I would like Lake Tahoe to be cropped from the big map if possible. Thanks in advance

[image]

Comment: What content do you need? The area covered by water or the land area?

Comment: Land and water. Basically close to what the screenshot shows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `tmap` it's possible when using OSM tiles as basemap:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(tmap)
library(tmaptools)
 
# define bounding box around Lake Tahoe and get OSM data
ext <- 0.2
bbox_tahoe <- bb(c(-120.02 - ext, 39.1 - ext, -120.02 + ext, 39.1 + ext))
osm <- read_osm(bbox_tahoe) 

# plot OSM tiles as basemap
tm_shape(osm) + 
  tm_rgb()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-08-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>